# user-defined form validation in grails

Tags: grails, validation

I am learning grails by doing some sample programs.
I want to know how to validate a user-defined form using grails.
My code is:

Domain class

```
class User
{
    String property

    static constraints = 
    {
        property(blank:false,nullable:false)
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
def addUser() {

}

def userPrint() {
      def values = request.getParameterValues("property")
      for(val in values){
         println "values received :"+val
      }
}
```

addUser.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<g:form name="useraddform" url="[controller:'user',action:'userPrint']">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username :</td>
<td><g:textField name="property" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password : </td>
<td><g:textField name="property" value=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="ADD"/>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to validate the username and password entered.
How to achieve this???
Please help....!

Comment: Downvoting because the question is lacking essential research..

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [constraints](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#constraints) manual section and whole [web layer](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html) chapter.

Also, run [`grails generate-all`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html) on some other sample project and look at scaffolding GSPs contents, especially [hasErrors](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/hasErrors.html) tag/function.

Comment: I have went through all the links related to grails validation, but i cant find how to map the fields and validate it... Please let me know how to validate the fields I mentioned.

Comment: Please also run thru the process of `grails generate-all`, examine every new structure and refer to the chapters again.

Comment: I went through and now validation is happening. But there is one problem. I am getting both username and password fields in the same name 'property'. In my controller I am getting the property as an array. While validating it is not validating this array. What should I do for this.

Comment: Then 1. Change `name="property"` to `name="email"` and `name="password"`. 2. Return some Model from an `addUser` action, like: def addUser() { [userInstance: new User()] }. 3. Add `g:hasErrors` tag and a `hasErrors` function to input styles. 4. Frankly, did you actually go thru the steps I recommended you?

Comment: Sorry to ask again and again. But my requirement says that I have to get both username and password fields in the same name 'property'. If I'm not giving values for those fields it is taking by default the value like [,,] and thus the validation gets true. What should I do for this???

Comment: We'll violate SO rules if we continue to discuss it here. You'll have to create a new question and do a good job on showing your research: what are the requirements, what you tried, what didn't work. Maybe you also should use "homework" tag.